# PE - DOS signature (MZ) and Little Endian

Tags: signature, portable-executable, endianness, magic-numbers

this is not a serious problem but **I am curious why DOS signature is 0x5A4D not 0x4D5A**

DOS Header's first member is MZ which is DOS signature named by *Mark Zbikowski*.

Below code is the part of DOS header.

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
  WORD e_magic;    // DOS signature : 4D5A ("MZ")
}
```

If Mark Zbikowski wants to write his name at the first of PE File, why didn't he write the code 0x4D5A but 0x5A4D ?? **Following the principle of Little Endian, that is ZM not MZ.**

Do I have wrong concept?

Comment: ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/jLUiqk4.png)
I open notepad.exe with Hex Editor to see DOS Header.

Comment: Following the principle of Little Endian if you have word e.g.: 0x1234 it is stored as 0x34 0x12. In source code you may see 0x5a4d, once you store it in memory then it looks like 0x4d 0x5a.

Comment: Ah, OK. You mean that 0x5A4D is right. In my reversing books, writer said " DOS signature is 4D5A which is "MZ" " So, I was confused. Thanks!